# Dimensions dmcli: is it possible to upload files on a subfolder of a project?

Tags: serena

The subject says it all. I have a bunch of files in a local workspace: I am able to select the ones I want with /USER_FILTER  parameter, but they are saved related to the root folder of the workset, while I would like to put them in a subfolder.

Apart from moving those files in a local subfolder with the corrisponding name so that they will be put in the correct place, is there some other way to do this from within dmcli?

Comment: I highly doubt there would be any other way. As far as documentation goes it always suggest to move files relative to your working root folder before delivering it to dimension. I think the reason for this would be how dimension tracks changes in the folder and files its own `.metadata` folder, or after version 12.2 using a `.dm` folder.

Comment: Indeed I eventually ended up doing so. Thanks!